# Is there any way to modify Standard profile

Tags: deployment, ant, workbench

I am trying to provide some permissions to objects in **Read Only** standard profile.
Using **UI** i am not able to change the object permissions.

Is there any way i can achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

**NO**. We cannot modify "Standard Profiles". The only way to achieve this is to "Clone" the standard profile, modify the permissions on the cloned profile and assign the cloned profile to the user.

From the [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_securing_data_standard_profiles.htm):

> You can find more detailed descriptions of all the standard profiles in the [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=standard_profiles.htm&language=en), **but the important thing to know is that you can never edit the object permissions on a standard profile**. If you have access to the Enterprise, Unlimited, Performance, or Developer Editions of the platform, **it’s a good idea to make copies of the standard profiles and then customize the copies to fit the needs of your organization.** You can also use permission sets to grant additional permissions

Comment: but we can modify standard profile as well by using package and deploying using ant/workbench.

Comment: @ajaybagdad Could you please elaborate how exactly you have edited the profile using Workbench? I tried updating a profile through workbench but it is throwing "You May Not Modify The Permission View All Data While Editing A Standard Profile; You May Not Modify The Permission View Event Log Files While Editing A Standard Profile" message.

Comment: i am talking about Field level security and Object permissions only .what you need to do is create a package file for standard profile and change the permissions as you need.deploy this package using workbench